# Winsocket server. File opening issue

Tags: c, file, winsock2

I have created simple TCP server using *winsock2.h* library. It translates english words into lithuanian for clients. I recieve query from client like this:

```
int MAXRECV = 100;
char *buffer;
buffer =  (char*) malloc((MAXRECV + 1) * sizeof(char));
valread = recv(new_socket, buffer, MAXRECV, 0);
buffer[valread] = '\0';
```

After that, I want to open a dictionary and find that word translation in a file. Here is a function call and function itself.

```
char *lithuanianWord;
lithuanianWord = (char*) malloc((MAXWORDSIZE + 1) * sizeof(char));
if (findTranslation(buffer, &lithuanianWord)) {
    send(new_socket, lithuanianWord, strlen(lithuanianWord), 0);
} else {
    lithuanianWord = "Translation not found";
    send(new_socket, lithuanianWord, strlen(lithuanianWord), 0);
}   

int findTranslation (char* word, char** lithuanianWord) {
    FILE *fp;
    int translationFound = 0;
    const char englishWord[50];
    char buffer[255];

    fp = fopen("*\\dictionary.txt","r");

    while((fgets(buffer,255,fp)) != NULL) {
        sscanf(buffer,"%s%s", englishWord, lithuanianWord);
        if(strcmp(englishWord, word)==0 ) {
            translationFound = 1;
            break;
        } 
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return translationFound;
}
```

Code compiles and runs perfectly. The problem is that txt file does not open  and answer is always "Translation not found". This function works fine when stand alone. Path is **full** and **the same**, I just shortened it.
Error I get: ***No such file or directory***. Both client and server are runing on the same hardware.

## Update: full server code.

```
#include<io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<string.h>

int findTranslation (char* word, char** translation);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET master , new_socket, client_socket[30], s;
struct sockaddr_in server , address;
int max_clients = 30, activity, addrlen, i, valread;
char *lithuanianWord;
int MAXWORDSIZE = 100;
lithuanianWord = (char*) malloc((MAXWORDSIZE + 1) * sizeof(char));

 //size of our receive buffer, this is string length.
int MAXRECV = 100;
//set of socket descriptors
fd_set readfds;
//1 extra for null character, string termination
char *buffer, *message;
buffer =  (char*) malloc((MAXRECV + 1) * sizeof(char));

for(i = 0 ; i < 30;i++)
{
    client_socket[i] = 0;
}

printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}    
printf("Initialised.\n");
 
//Create a socket
if((master = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} 
printf("Socket created.\n");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(master ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}   
puts("Bind done");

listen(master , 3);
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

for(;;)
{
    //clear the socket fd set
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    //add master socket to fd set
    FD_SET(master, &readfds);
     
    //add child sockets to fd set
    for (  i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
    {
        s = client_socket[i];
        if(s > 0)
        {
            FD_SET( s , &readfds);
        }
    }
    
    //wait for an activity on any of the sockets, timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
    activity = select( 0 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

    if ( activity == SOCKET_ERROR ) 
    {
        printf("select call failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
    if (FD_ISSET(master , &readfds)) 
    {
        if ((new_socket = accept(master , (struct sockaddr *)&address, (int *)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      
        //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
        printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
          
        //add new socket to array of sockets
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
        {
            if (client_socket[i] == 0)
            {
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                printf("Adding to list of sockets at index %d \n" , i);
                break;
            }
        }

    valread = recv(new_socket, buffer, MAXRECV, 0);
    buffer[valread] = '\0';
    printf("%s:%d - %s \n" , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port), buffer);
    
    int i = findTranslation(buffer, &lithuanianWord);   
    if (i == 1) {
        send(new_socket, lithuanianWord, strlen(lithuanianWord), 0);
        } else {
        lithuanianWord = "Vertimas nerastas";
        send(new_socket, lithuanianWord, strlen(lithuanianWord), 0);
        }   
}

//else its some IO operation on some other socket 
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
    {
        s = client_socket[i];
        //if client present in read sockets             
        if (FD_ISSET( s , &readfds)) 
        {
            //get details of the client
            getpeername(s , (struct sockaddr*)&address , (int*)&addrlen);

            //Check if it was for closing , and also read the incoming message
            //recv does not place a null terminator at the end of the string (whilst printf %s assumes there is one).
            valread = recv( s , buffer, MAXRECV, 0);
            buffer[valread] = '\0';
            
            if( valread == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
                if(error_code == WSAECONNRESET)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                    printf("Host disconnected unexpectedly , ip %s , port %d \n" , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
                  
                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                    closesocket( s );
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("recv failed with error code : %d" , error_code);
                }
            }
            if ( valread == 0)
            {
                //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
                  
                //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                closesocket( s );
                client_socket[i] = 0;
            }
              
            //Echo back the message that came in
            else
            {
              i = findTranslation(buffer, &lithuanianWord);
               if (i == 1) {
                    send(s, lithuanianWord, strlen(lithuanianWord), 0);
                    } else {
                    lithuanianWord = "Vertimas nerastas";
                    send(s, lithuanianWord, strlen(lithuanianWord), 0);
                    }   
            }
        }
    }
}

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
  
return 0;
}

int findTranslation (char* word, char** lithuanianWord) {
FILE *fp;
int translationFound = 0;
const char englishWord[50];
char buffer[255];

fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Martynas\\Documents\\Programų_sistemos\\IV semestras\\Tinklai\\async\\dictionary.txt","r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error");
}
while((fgets(buffer,255,fp)) != NULL) {
sscanf(buffer,"%s%s", englishWord, lithuanianWord);
if(strcmp(englishWord, word)==0 ) {
    translationFound = 1;
    break;
} 
}
fclose(fp);
return translationFound;
}
```

Comment: rule number one: always check return value of function.

Comment: @Stargateur Return values are fine, I don't get why server cannot find a file while simple application can.

Comment: Why are you allocating 1025 bytes for the `recv()` buffer when you only read 100 bytes max? You are also not taking into account that `recv()` reads arbitrary bytes, it is not guaranteed to read complete words/sentences in one go. You need to implement a *protocol* in your communications so you can delimit your word data.  You may have to call `recv()` multiple times before you encounter your delimiter.

Comment: As for the text file itself, you are opening it using a *relative path*, so  chances are the calling process's **current working directory** is not pointing where you think it is. That would account for why the file is not found. Always use *absolute paths*.  And you are not allocating any memory at all to receive the `lithuanianWord` data from `sscanf()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for review. In fact, I am using _absolute path_, just shortened it for displaying reasons. I updated my question.

Comment: @Unknown "Return values are fine", oh really? So why do you update your question with "Error I get: No such file or directory" and what it's hard to understand about this error?

Comment: @Stargateur Because file really exists and I am using _absolute path_. It works fine when compiled in simple c code, does not work when in TCP server code (talking about working with file) Must be something deeper than _no such file or directory_

Comment: @Unknown Well give us the true server.c, because your bug is currently impossible to reproduce.

Comment: I run this without error, your path is probably wrong maybe this char `ų`.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, it is because of that char. Thank you! Not working properly, but at least, file opens now.

Comment: Modern OS pretend to process non ascii characters in file name. They indeed do but **you** will fall in traps if you do. Just revert to good all ascii for filenames (and be sure to have consistent case if you expect portability) and life will be better... Keep utf for data, not for metadata